Prisma - Next.js API - Postgres - unable to update an array

I have Room and Video models, each room has an array of Videos .
I'm building a PUT route: it takes a Video as a param, the PUT route will move that video to the first position in the videos array, then perform update to the database with Prisma. At the end, the videos array did not get updated at all.

Here are my Prisma models:
model Room {
  id       String  @id @default(cuid())
  roomName String? @unique
  videos   Video[]
  user     User    @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  userId   String

  @@index([userId])
}

model Video {
  id             String  @id @default(cuid())
  youtubeVideoId String?
  thumbnail      String?
  url            String?
  title          String?
  room           Room?   @relation(fields: [roomName], references: [roomName], onDelete: Cascade)
  roomName       String?

  @@index([roomName])
}

Here is my PUT route (simplified error handling logics):
export async function PUT(req: NextRequest) {
  const session = await getServerSession(nextAuthOptions);
  const body: Video = await req.json();
  

  const currentRoom = await prisma.room.findUnique({
    where: {
      roomName: body.roomName,
      userId: session.id,
    },
    include: {
      videos: true,
    },
  });

  const videoIndex = currentRoom.videos.findIndex(
    (video) => video.id === body.id,
  );

  const pulledVideo = currentRoom.videos.splice(videoIndex, 1)[0];
  currentRoom.videos.unshift(pulledVideo)

  const updatedRoom = await prisma.room.update({
    where: {
      userId: session.id,
      roomName: body.roomName,
    },
    include: {
      videos: true,
    },
    data: {
      videos: {
        set: currentRoom.videos,
      },
    },
  });

  return NextResponse.json(updatedRoom.videos);
}

I've tested in different scenarios, still have not figured out, and really appreciate if someone can give me a direction:

The update does not work if I set the videos with updatedVideos
The prisma.room.updates works if I set the videos with currentRoom.videos (the remaining array), or even Array(pulledVideo)
If I console.log(updatedVideos), it shows the correct array that I want to set. But the result value of the prisma.room.update did not change from the original.

